# Issue with getting an object results from an array in PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I am building a Twitter API and part of it gets the users info:

```
$watchAccInfo = $connection->get('users/show/'.$watchAccount.'');
```

From here I dump the objects and store it:

```
$value = get_object_vars($watchAccInfo);
```

Then I echo the part I want:

```
echo $value["text"];
```

The problem is echo `$value["text"]; = null.`

I am not to sure why and if you could give me a hand I would appreciate it!

EDIT:

When I use the json_decode() I get `Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string`

Comment: what does `$watchAccInfo->test` give you?

Comment: var_dump($watchAccInfo) and see if text is in fact NULL.

Comment: Twitter returns a JSON string, are you using `json_decode()` on the fetched data before you pass it to `get_object_vars()`?

Comment: try, json_decode($data, TRUE) to convert to assoc array.  Otherwise it will be a standard object.

Comment: @jon it gives me nothing is I do $watchAccInfo->test

Comment: @Cryptic No I am not using the json_decode

Comment: David, are you using the Twitter API? Or Making your own?  The value isn't being assigned to the object via method `get`, which is where your problem lies.

Comment: I am using the Twitter API....I am not to sure!

Comment: Well when I print out the initial value I get the whole object and all it's values..I am trying to access the Object's [text]' part because it contains the most recent status.